# definitely not a truck driver

Tags: meaning-in-context, modal-verbs

> Would you like to be a truck driver?
>
> No, **I wouldn't definitely like to be** a truck driver.

Is the above sentence grammatically correct? 
Can I replace "I wouldn't definitely like to be" with the below? Is it still has the same meaning?

> No, **definitely not** a truck driver

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> No, I wouldn't definitely like to be a truck driver.

In this construction, *not* is taken to modify *definitely* and *definitely* is taken to modify only the complement, *like to be a truck driver*; you're saying that you **would** like to be a truck driver, but not definitely: only tentatively or conditionally.

What you probably mean is

> No, I definitely wouldn't like to be a truck driver, *or*
>   No, I would definitely not like to be a truck driver.

—that is, it is quite certain that you would **not** like to be a truck driver.

As a response to the question "Would you like to be a truck driver?",

> No, definitely not a truck driver

would be understood to have the second meaning, not the first: you **don't** want to be a truck driver.